# How to Loop Through Type SyndicationFeed to Output RSS to View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to output my RSS feed in my view like this:

```
@ModelType IEnumerable(Of MyBlog.RssModel)

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Title
        </th>
        <th>
            Description
        </th>
        <th>
            Link
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@For Each item In Model
    Dim currentItem = item
    @<tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) currentItem.Title)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) currentItem.Description)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) currentItem.Link)
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
Next

</table>
```

Here is my code:

```
Function ShowFeed() As ActionResult

    Dim feedUrl = "http://www.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/HomePage.xml"
    Dim feed As SyndicationFeed = GetFeed(feedUrl)

    Dim model As IList(Of RssModel) = New List(Of RssModel)()

    For Each item As SyndicationItem In feed.Items
        Dim rss As New RssModel()
        rss.Title = item.Title.ToString
        rss.Description = item.Summary.ToString
        rss.Link = item.Links.ToString

        model.Add(rss)
    Next

    Return View(model)

End Function
```

Yields unexpected result:

> Title  Description     Link
>   System.ServiceModel.Syndication.TextSyndicationContent
>   System.ServiceModel.Syndication.TextSyndicationContent
>   System.ServiceModel.Syndication.NullNotAllowedCollection`1[System.ServiceModel.Syndication.SyndicationLink]
>
>   System.ServiceModel.Syndication.TextSyndicationContent
>
>   System.ServiceModel.Syndication.TextSyndicationContent
>
>   System.ServiceModel.Syndication.NullNotAllowedCollection`1[System.ServiceModel.Syndication.SyndicationLink]
>   System.ServiceModel.Syndication.TextSyndicationContent
>   System.ServiceModel.Syndication.TextSyndicationContent
>   System.ServiceModel.Syndication.NullNotAllowedCollection`1[System.ServiceModel.Syndication.SyndicationLink]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is this:

```
Function ShowFeed() As ActionResult

        Dim feedUrl = "http://www.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/HomePage.xml"
        Dim feed As SyndicationFeed = GetFeed(feedUrl)

        Dim model As IList(Of RssModel) = New List(Of RssModel)()

        For Each item As SyndicationItem In feed.Items
            Dim rss As New RssModel()
            rss.Title = item.Title.Text
            rss.Description = item.Summary.Text
            rss.Link = item.Links.First.Uri.ToString

            model.Add(rss)
        Next

        Return View(model)

    End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

your `Return View(viewModel)` is returning a single RssModel, instead of a list of RssModels. You should create an IEnumerable(of RssModel) and populate it in your For Each loop, then return the IEnumerable to the View.

> > EDIT: Used code converter from c# to vb, but this should show you to progress.

```
Dim model As IList(Of RssModel) = New List(Of RssModel)()

For Each item As var In feed
    Dim rss As New RssModel()
    rss.Something = item.Something

    model.Add(rss)
Next

Return View(model.AsEnumerable(Of RssModel)())
```

Comment: Thanks, Rob.  Can you show me an example of how to create an IEnumberable(of RSSModel) and populate it in a For Each loop?

Comment: I get the same error on "feed" which says I can't use a foreach loop on it "Error 1 Expression is of type 'System.ServiceModel.Syndication.SyndicationFeed', which is not a collection type."

Comment: The problem was that I had to change "feed" to "feed.items."  However, it get an unexpected result.  I updated the question.  Can you help with this?  Please let me know, so I can otherwise open a new question.

Comment: I found the answer.  This blog really helped http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/RSSAtomFeed_2.aspx